# A symbol of triangle with "infinite" length

Tags: symbols

I want to know if there is a way to create a symbol of triangle like $\Delta$ (which I use to mean a bounded triangle) but each edge goes slightly father across the vertex (rather than stop at the vertex as usual).

Using this I was to mean a 2D plane sitting in the 3D space like the one defined by the equation $x+y+z=1$, hence not bounded triangle (so I want a symbol different from $\Delta$ ). Consider various dimension, they will form a cosimplicial affine space.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like any reasonable pizza place, LaTeX offers "build your own".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\inftrian}{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.25em]
\draw[line width=0.075em] (-45:0.5em) -- (105:0.5em) (-15:0.5em) -- (-165:0.5em) (-135:0.5em) -- (75:0.5em);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
ABC \inftrian\ DEF
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice, thanks! One more question: is it possible to make the line more black (boldface)?

Comment: @Lao-tzu Sure. You can choose any line width. I chose a slightly thicker one in my update.