# How to write a dashed congruent sign?

Tags: symbols, relation-symbols

I wanna to write a symbol like this:[image]

I tried`\dashcong` but it did not work. Does it require a new command? I hope someone can share the code.

Comment: You should check [the answers here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-letter-from-a-math-alphabet-or-other-chara) out first, but in this case, I’m not aware of any package that contains it.  You might build it with `\overset` from `amsmath`. (You’d need `aligned-overset` if you want to be able to align your equations at this symbol.)

Comment: Or you could draw it in tikz and wrap it in `\mathrel`.

Comment: I tried but this symbol does not exist. Maybe it require a now definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make your own symbol using the techniques from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/480769/125871). Here is a version using `reflectbox` from the `graphicx` package to make a reflected `\cong` symbol. Then `\ooalign` is used to superimpose two white rules to make the dash pattern. You can adjust the spacing of the dashes to your liking.

[image]

If you want your symbol to adjust to scriptsize you can use `\mathpalette` or `\mathchoice`. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34412/125871) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/480769/125871).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} %for \reflectbox
\usepackage{color} %for \textcolor

\newcommand{\dashcong}{\mathrel{\ooalign{\reflectbox{$\cong$}\cr\hfil\textcolor{white}{\rule[.5ex]{.13em}{.3ex}\hspace{.13em}\rule[.5ex]{.13em}{.3ex}}\hfil\cr}}}

\begin{document}

$A\dashcong B$

\end{document}
```