# Why is \nsim thicker than \sim?

Tags: amssymb, mathdesign

### Problem

For some reason, `\nsim` looks like a negated **bold** version of `\sim`, while I would expect it to look exactly like `\sim` with a slash on top of it.

---

### Examples

This seems to happen with `mathdesign`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\scalebox{10}{%
$\sim$
$\nsim$
\makebox[0pt][l]{$\nsim$}%
\color{red}$\sim$%
}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

It looks like this (note that `\nsim` is thicker than `\sim`; it is easiest to see when we overlay a red `\sim` on top of a black `\nsim`):

[image: mathdesign]

And it also seems to happen with `amssymb`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\scalebox{10}{%
$\sim$
$\nsim$
\makebox[0pt][l]{$\nsim$}%
\color{red}$\sim$%
}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

It looks like this (again black `\nsim` is visible under red `\sim`):

[image: amssymb]

---

### Questions

1. Why does this happen? Isn't `\nsim` supposed to be a negated `\sim`?
2. How can I construct with `\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}` a symbol that looks like a negated version of `\sim`? (Something like `\not\sim` is ugly.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the issue seems to be with the definition of `\nsim`, I suggest you redefine it:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\nsim}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\n@sim\relax}}
\newcommand{\n@sim}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    $\m@th#1\sim$\cr
    \hidewidth$\m@th#1\rotatebox[origin=c]{50}{$#1-$}$\hidewidth\cr
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

For users unfamiliar with `\mathpalette`: [The mysteries of \mathpalette](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34393/125871)

For general advice on designing your own symbols: [How do you make your own symbol when Detexify fails?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/480768/125871)

For additional details regarding `\ooalign`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22375/125871

To use the above code, the call `$a\nsim b_{a\nsim b_{a\nsim b}}$` produces the output
[image]

Since the original `\sim` command is used to redefine `\nsim`, the thickness is equal:

[image]

Using `mathdesign`:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is great! With `mathdesign` I decided to use `60` instead of `50` in `\rotatebox`, but other than that, this worked flawlessly and looks very good to me!

Answer (score 9):

It seems that it depends on the font — the `\nsim` glyph is a different glyph and not made by composition (which, with the default fonts for `article` class, comes out quite ugly):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\scalebox{10}{%
$\sim$
$\nsim$
\makebox[0pt][l]{$\nsim$}%
\color{red}$\sim$%
}

\scalebox{10}{%
$\sim$
$\not\sim$
\makebox[0pt][l]{$\not\sim$}%
\color{red}$\sim$%
}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `stix2` fonts things are (in my opinion) much better:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{stix2}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\scalebox{10}{%
$\sim$
$\nsim$
\makebox[0pt][l]{$\nsim$}%
\color{red}$\sim$%
}

\scalebox{10}{%
$\sim$
$\not\sim$
\makebox[0pt][l]{$\not\sim$}%
\color{red}$\sim$%
}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

...and looking at the example, I think that `amssymb` is using the stix glyph under the hood...

Comment: Sorry, `\documentclass` wasn't visible as I had a mistake with Markdown, now fixed, yes, it was `article`.

Comment: Since `amssymb` predates `stix` by decades, it's highly unlikely that the `stix` glyph is used under the hood in the former.  (You're certainly correct that more care should have been taken in making sure the negated symbol was different in *only* the negation.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton so probably it was the other way around... ;-)

Answer (score 4):

With `amssymb`, the `\thicksim` and `\nsim` are a pair, but `\sim` and `\nsim` are not. To get more consistent output, you can redefine `\sim` to `\thicksim` by `\let\sim\thicksim`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[blend group=screen, scale=10, every node/.style={scale=10}]
  \node[red] {$\sim$};
  \node[blue] {$\nsim$};
  
  \begin{scope}[xshift=10pt]
    \node[red] {$\thicksim$};
    \node[blue] {$\nsim$};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Related implementations:

```tex
% latex2e kernel
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols} {OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sim}      {\mathrel}{symbols}{"18}

% amsfonts.sty
\DeclareSymbolFont{AMSb}    {U}{msb}{m}{n}
% amssymb.sty
\DeclareMathSymbol{\thicksim} {\mathrel}{AMSb}{"73}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nsim}     {\mathrel}{AMSb}{"1C}
```