# How to create a dashed equality symbol?

Tags: symbols, relation-symbols

How to create a dashed equality symbol as follows?

[image]

Also, make sure that, it

- be effected by `\not` the same as `=`,
- and act the same as = in other ways.

By the way, it's not necessary that there must be three gaps in `=`.

Comment: It is possible to construct such a symbol (also `\not`able), but maybe another more common symbol is better suited. What do you want to express with the symbol? Maybe use `\stackrel?=`?

Comment: what length is that? the same as = or the same as ==== or something in between?

Comment: ⩶ is U+2A76 which is `\eqeqeq` in unicode-math, stix and stix2 packages.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The same as =.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a different solution using the `trimclip` package. This works with all sizes (large, Huge, etc.) as well as `scriptstyle` and `scriptscriptstyle`.

[image]

Instead of overlaying white onto an `=` sign, we clip portions of the `=` sign and replace with whitespace. I selected the left, middle and right 1/4 of the `=` sign indicated in the code as `.25\weq` (left quarter) followed by an eighth space (`.125\weq`) followed by the middle quarter (`.375\weq` to `.625\weq`), etc. You can adjust the spacing however you wish, or subdivide the `=` even more.

**Update**

Here are two additional versions where the clipping only affects one of the lines. Instead of inserting space between the segments, a clipped `=` symbol is inserted. When the bottom portion is clipped (`\eqeqeqb`) the baseline changes so a `\raisebox` command is used.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{trimclip}

\newlength{\weq}
\newlength{\heq}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\eqeqeq}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\eq@eq\relax}}
\newcommand{\eq@eq}[2]{\settowidth{\weq}{$\m@th#1=$}%
    \clipbox*{0pt 0pt {.25\weq} \height}{$\m@th#1=$}%
    \hspace{.125\weq}%
    \clipbox*{{.375\weq} 0pt {.625\weq} \height}{$\m@th#1=$}%
    \hspace{.125\weq}%
    \clipbox*{{.75\weq} 0pt {\weq} \height}{$\m@th#1=$}%
}
\newcommand{\eqeqeqt}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\eq@eqt\relax}}
\newcommand{\eq@eqt}[2]{\settowidth{\weq}{$\m@th#1=$}%
    \clipbox*{0pt 0pt {.25\weq} \height}{$\m@th#1=$}%
    \clipbox*{{.25\weq} 0pt {.375\weq} {.5\height}}{$\m@th#1=$}%
    \clipbox*{{.375\weq} 0pt {.625\weq} \height}{$\m@th#1=$}%
    \clipbox*{{.625\weq} 0pt {.75\weq} {.5\height}}{$\m@th#1=$}%
    \clipbox*{{.75\weq} 0pt {\weq} \height}{$\m@th#1=$}%
}
\newcommand{\eqeqeqb}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\eq@eqb\relax}}
\newcommand{\eq@eqb}[2]{\settowidth{\weq}{$\m@th#1=$}\settoheight{\heq}{$\m@th#1=$}%
    \clipbox*{0pt 0pt {.25\weq} \height}{$\m@th#1=$}%
    \raisebox{.5\heq}{\clipbox*{{.25\weq} {.5\height} {.375\weq} {\height}}{$\m@th#1=$}}%
    \clipbox*{{.375\weq} 0pt {.625\weq} \height}{$\m@th#1=$}%
    \raisebox{.5\heq}{\clipbox*{{.625\weq} {.5\height} {.75\weq} {\height}}{$\m@th#1=$}}%
    \clipbox*{{.75\weq} 0pt {\weq} \height}{$\m@th#1=$}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A=B_{a=b_{x=y}}$

$A\eqeqeq B_{a\eqeqeq b_{x\eqeqeq y}}$

$A\eqeqeqt B_{a\eqeqeqt b_{x\eqeqeqt y}}$

$A\eqeqeqb B_{a\eqeqeqb b_{x\eqeqeqb y}}$

$A\ne B_{a\ne b_{x\ne y}}$

$A\not\eqeqeq B_{a\not\eqeqeq b_{x\not\eqeqeq y}}$

$A\not\eqeqeqt B_{a\not\eqeqeqt b_{x\not\eqeqeqt y}}$

$A\not\eqeqeqb B_{a\not\eqeqeqb b_{x\not\eqeqeqb y}}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: Could you use this way to give a equality symbol which has only one dashed line not two?

Comment: @M.Logic: Yes. Just change `=` to `-` in the expression `$\m@th#1=$` (4 times)

Comment: Maybe I didn't speak clearly. What I mean to is a symbol with two lines but there is only one dashed line.

Comment: @M.Logic: Oh, I misunderstood. Do you want the top line or the bottom to be dashed?

Comment: Both. Exactly, one way to control the location of clipbox.

Comment: @M.Logic: I updated my response. You can do any of the 3 versions now: `\eqeqeq` dashes both lines, `\eqeqeqt` dashes the top, `\eqeqeqb` dashes the bottom.

Comment: Thanks very much

Answer (score 6):

You can make your own symbol using the techniques from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/480769/125871). Here is a version using `\ooalign` to superimpose two white rules on an `=` symbol to make the dash pattern. You can adjust the spacing and thickness of the gaps to your liking by changing the arguments in `\hspace` and `\rule`. Note that if your page color is not white you'll have to change the color of the rules.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color} %for \textcolor

\newcommand{\eqeqeq}{\mathrel{\ooalign{=\cr\hfil\textcolor{white}{\rule[.28ex]{.1em}{.6ex}\hspace{.2em}\rule[.28ex]{.1em}{.6ex}}\hfil\cr}}}

\begin{document}

$A\eqeqeq B$

$A\not\eqeqeq B$

$A=B$

$A\ne B$

\end{document}
```

If you need the symbol in `\scriptstyle` or `\scriptscriptstyle`, you can use `\mathchoice`:

```
\newcommand{\eqeqeq}{\mathrel{
   \mathchoice
     {\ooalign{=\cr\hfil\textcolor{white}{\rule[.28ex]{.1em}{.6ex}\hspace{.2em}\rule[.28ex]{.1em}{.6ex}}\hfil\cr}}
     {\ooalign{=\cr\hfil\textcolor{white}{\rule[.28ex]{.1em}{.6ex}\hspace{.2em}\rule[.28ex]{.1em}{.6ex}}\hfil\cr}}
     {\ooalign{$\scriptstyle{=}$\cr\hfil\textcolor{white}{\rule[.17ex]{.08em}{.47ex}\hspace{.18em}\rule[.17ex]{.08em}{.47ex}}\hfil\cr}}
     {\ooalign{$\scriptscriptstyle{=}$\cr\hfil\textcolor{white}{\rule[.1ex]{.06em}{.38ex}\hspace{.17em}\rule[.1ex]{.06em}{.38ex}}\hfil\cr}}
}}
```

[image]

Again, you can adjust the spacing and thickness of the gaps however you like.

Comment: Could you give an improvement to make it adjust to  scriptsize?

Comment: @M.Logic, I updated my response.

Comment: Oops!  It looks like the value of `em` is stuck at `\normalsize`.  It might be possible to salvage this by explicitly specifying the desired size for each stage.  (This should probably be investigated directly at the level of `\mathchoice`, but that's digging deeper than I feel comfortable doing.)

Comment: @Sandy G When we use huge fontsize over such symbol, the white line will cover parts of the `\not` line.

Comment: @M.Logic, I posted a different solution that resolves the fontsize issue.