# strecthed \wedge

Tags: formatting

I was wondering how to write that symbol in latex?
the \wedge does not look fine since it looks too acute.

[image]

Comment: how are you using that, `\widehat{abc}` if it is an accent

Comment: In what context do you want it? Just like a wedge but wider? Or as an accent?

Comment: @mickep, I want to use it as an index for function, i.e. $f_{\wedge}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this does what you want, but you could use `\scalebox` to scale `\wedge` vertically but not horizontally. Of course you can change the scale factors however you want. This is assuming you're only going to use the symbol as a subscript. If you plan on using the symbol in other ways, I suggest you take a look at [a more general solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/480769/125871) using `mathchoice` or `mathpalette`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\newwedge}{\scalebox{1}[0.5]{$\scriptstyle\wedge$}}

\begin{document}

$f_{\newwedge}$ vs. $f_{\wedge}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! The first symbol this is what I wanted!