# How do I create a custom math mode binary operation symbol that is a combination of two binary operation symbols?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators, stacking-symbols, relation-symbols

I want to create two math mode binary operation symbols:

##### (1) A combination of `-` (minus symbol) and `*` (asterisk)

##### (2) A combination of `/` (slash symbol) and `*` (asterisk)

The desired result would be something that looks like the following but is kerned and centered properly and has the left-right spacing of a typical binary operation:

[image: a \minusast b = c \slashast d.]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\Huge\[a \mathbin{-\mkern-11.5mu*} b = c \mathbin{/\mkern-8.875mu*} d.\] % my makeshift solution
\end{document}
```

```
\[a \minusast b = c \slashast d.\] % desired macro names and syntax
```

My question is:

#### How do I create the custom math mode binary relation symbols (1) and (2)?

It would also be nice if there's a version of (2) where the `/` symbol is adjusted to be a diagonal axis of symmetry of the `*` symbol.

#### If it's also possible, how do I generally create a custom math mode binary operation symbol that is a combination of two binary operation symbols?

Thank you.

Comment: What is your minimal working example? Please add the tex code  in your question.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/480768/125871

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this? (updated to take into account the OP's additional requirement)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{graphicx} % for '\rotatebox' macro
\newcommand\myslash{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-30}{$\vert$}}

\newcommand\minusast{\mathbin{\ooalign{\hss$*$\hss\cr$-$}}}
\newcommand\slashast{\mathbin{\ooalign{\hss$*$\hss\cr$\myslash$}}}

\begin{document}
$a\minusast b = c \slashast d$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. This answer should suffice but as I stated in the question, I was wondering if there is a way to make a custom `/` such that it divides the asterisk `*` into two symmetric halves diagonally. So the `/` would be slightly tilted clockwise.

Comment: @AmanuensisFrances - I'll need to think about this for a sec...

Comment: @AmanuensisFrances - Please see the updated answer. The main change is that I've replaced `/` with a vertical bar that's been rotated 30 degrees clockwise. (The `/` symbols is rotated "only" 20 degrees from vertical...)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: An additional observation: The macros `\minusast` and `\slashast` shown above work for `\displaystyle` and `\textstyle` math. If you need to use them in level-1 or (shudder) level-2 subscript and superscript positions as well, you should employ the versions of the macros provided in the answers of [SandyG](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/673668/5001) and [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/673677/5001).

Answer (score 4):

The following will work in `scriptstyle` and `scriptscriptstyle`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\asth}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\ast@h\relax}}
\newcommand{\ast@h}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    \hfil$\m@th#1*$\hfil\cr
    \hfil\rotatebox[origin=c]{-30}{$\m@th#1\mid$}\hfil\cr
  }%
}
\newcommand{\astd}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\ast@d\relax}}
\newcommand{\ast@d}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    \hfil$\m@th#1*$\hfil\cr
    $\m@th#1-$\cr
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a*b\asth c\astd a$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are the `*` and rotated-slash symbols aligned on the same center? And should the new symbols be of type `mathbin` rather than `mathrel`?

Comment: @Mico: Yes, `mathbin` not `mathrel`. Don't know what I was thinking. As for the centers, I believe they are the same, but the rotation should happen outside the switch to math mode. Fixed now.

Comment: +1 I wonder whether the apparent slight asymmetry in the slash is a rendering issue of the pdf viewer. (Can't test now, but rotating math can be tricky, I remember writing an extra macro for that.)

Comment: @campa: I think it's a viewer issue. At 2000% there is no apparent asymmetry.

Answer (score 4):

The idea is to use `\mathpalette` and `\ooalign`. Some tricks are necessary, though: a `\vphantom{*}` ensures the correct bounding box, because `\ooalign` gets the height from the first item and the depth from the second one.

For the slash, one can use `\centernot` from the eponymous package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{centernot}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\astminus}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\astminus@\relax}}
\newcommand{\astminus@}[2]{%
  \vphantom{*}%
  \ooalign{\hidewidth$\m@th#1*$\hidewidth\cr$\m@th#1-$\cr}%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\astslash}{\mathbin{\centernot{*}}}

\begin{document}

$a\astminus b \astslash c$

$\scriptstyle a\astminus b \astslash c$

$\scriptscriptstyle a\astminus b \astslash c$

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different version where the `\astslash` symbol is obtained by rotating 60 degrees `\astminus`. Don't ask too much about how this is obtained.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% syntactic sugar
\newcommand{\xmathpalette}[2]{%
  \mathchoice
    {#1\displaystyle\textfont{#2}}
    {#1\textstyle\textfont{#2}}
    {#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont{#2}}
    {#1\scriptscriptstyle\scriptscriptfont{#2}}
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\astminus}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\astminus@\relax}}
\newcommand{\astminus@}[2]{%
  \vphantom{*}%
  \ooalign{\hidewidth$\m@th#1*$\hidewidth\cr$\m@th#1-$\cr}%
}

\newcommand{\astslash}{\mathbin{\xmathpalette\astslash@\relax}}
\newcommand{\astslash@}[3]{%
  \begingroup\settowidth\dimen@{$\m@th#1*$}%
  \makebox[\dimen@][s]{%
    \hspace{0pt minus 1fil}%
    \raisebox{0pt}[0.75\height][0.1\depth]{%
      \rotatebox[origin=c]{60}{%
        \raisebox{\dimexpr2\fontdimen22 #2 2 - \height}{%
          $\m@th#1\astminus$%
        }%
      }%
    }%
    \hspace{0pt minus 1.8fil}%
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\fboxsep=0pt\fboxrule=0.1pt
\fbox{$\astslash$}\fbox{$*$}

$a\astminus b \astslash c$

$\scriptstyle a\astminus b \astslash c$

$\scriptscriptstyle a\astminus b \astslash c$

\end{document}
```

A lot of visual formatting, but the main idea is simple. I lower the `\astminus` symbol so it lies on the baseline, then rotate it. The bounding box has been set by eye.

[image]

Comment: (Already upvoted several hours ago.) A factoid I wasn't aware of until now is that the slash symbol provided by `\centernot{ }` is tilted 30 degrees to the right, and not just 20 degrees as is the case for `/`. (Until now, I had simply assumed that the tilt angle was the same for both slash-y symbols.) Oddly, though, while centernot's centering of the slash symbol is fine if `\scriptstyle` is in effect, it's a tiny bit off if `\scriptscriptstyle` is in effect, possibly (likely?) because the tilt angle is noticeably larger if `\scriptscriptstyle` is in effect. Should I inform Heiko about this?

Comment: @Mico I don’t think Heiko can do anything about this: `\centernot` uses the `\not` symbol and that’s all it can get.