# \rightleftarrows in the style of \rightarrowtriangle

Tags: math-mode, symbols, arrows, stmaryrd

Is there a symbol for `\rightleftarrows` (an arrow to the right above an arrow to the left) but in the style of `\rightarrowtriangle` (an arrow with a hollow triangular head)?

Comment: You can stack the arrows yourself: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/stackengine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following, based on Sandy G's approach, works and is compatible with `\xymatrix`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[only,rightarrowtriangle,leftarrowtriangle]{stmaryrd}

\newcommand{\stackedarrowstriangle}[2]{\mathrel{\mathchoice
    {\mathrlap{\raisebox{.35ex}{$#1$}}\raisebox{-.35ex}{$#2$}}
    {\mathrlap{\raisebox{.35ex}{$#1$}}\raisebox{-.35ex}{$#2$}}
    {\mathrlap{\raisebox{.25ex}{$\scriptstyle#1$}}\raisebox{-.25ex}{$\scriptstyle#2$}}
    {\mathrlap{\raisebox{.2ex}{$\scriptscriptstyle#1$}}\raisebox{-.2ex}{$\scriptscriptstyle#2$}}
}}
    
\newcommand{\rightleftarrowstriangle}{\stackedarrowstriangle{\rightarrowtriangle}{\leftarrowtriangle}}
\newcommand{\leftrightarrowstriangle}{\stackedarrowstriangle{\leftarrowtriangle}{\rightarrowtriangle}}

\begin{document}

$A\leftrightarrowtriangle B_{A\leftrightarrowtriangle B_{A\leftrightarrowtriangle B}}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the lengths in the `\raisebox` commands if you want the symbol at a different height or a different amount of space between. For explanations of `\mathchoice` and `\ooalign`, as well as other ways of doing this, you can look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/480768/125871) and its solutions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[only,rightarrowtriangle,leftarrowtriangle]{stmaryrd}

\newcommand{\leftrightarrowtriangle}{\mathrel{\mathchoice
    {\ooalign{\raisebox{-.2ex}{$\rightarrowtriangle$}\cr\raisebox{.4ex}{$\leftarrowtriangle$}\cr}}
    {\ooalign{\raisebox{-.2ex}{$\rightarrowtriangle$}\cr\raisebox{.4ex}{$\leftarrowtriangle$}\cr}}
    {\ooalign{\raisebox{-.1ex}{$\scriptstyle\rightarrowtriangle$}\cr\raisebox{.35ex}{$\scriptstyle\leftarrowtriangle$}\cr}}
    {\ooalign{\raisebox{-.1ex}{$\scriptscriptstyle\rightarrowtriangle$}\cr\raisebox{.3ex}{$\scriptscriptstyle\leftarrowtriangle$}\cr}}
}}

\begin{document}

$A\leftrightarrowtriangle B_{A\leftrightarrowtriangle B_{A\leftrightarrowtriangle B}}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution does not work inside of an `\xymatrix`, probably due to the usage of `\cr`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for `\ialign` rather than `\ooalign`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leftrightarrowstriangle}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mathpalette\arrowstriangle@{\leftarrowtriangle\rightarrowtriangle}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\rightleftarrowstriangle}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mathpalette\arrowstriangle@{\rightarrowtriangle\leftarrowtriangle}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\arrowstriangle@}[2]{\arrowstriangle@@#1#2}
\newcommand{\arrowstriangle@@}[3]{%
  \vbox{%
    \offinterlineskip
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\rightarrowtriangle$}%
    \ialign{%
      $\m@th#1##$\cr % template
      #2\cr
      \noalign{\kern-0.4\ht\z@}
      #3\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\leftrightarrowstriangle B_{A\leftrightarrowstriangle B_{A\leftrightarrowstriangle B}}$

$A\rightleftarrowstriangle B_{A\rightleftarrowstriangle B_{A\rightleftarrowstriangle B}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm accepting Sandy G's answer for being comprehensible and editable without far-reaching LaTeX expertise.

Comment: @dremodaris If you like to dig holes with a fork and roll spaghetti with a spade… 