# How to create cleaner symbol for $\neg\cap$

Tags: symbols

I often use the intersection symbol with a line through it to denote disjoint sets when writing on paper or a whiteboard. However, I haven't found a way to do this in LaTex (just writing `$\neg\cap$` results in a misaligned line). Does anyone know how I could fix this? I am very new to Latex so am unfamiliar with how to do anything

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean `$\not\cap$`?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean `\not\cap`, which I agree looks bad. Instead you could use the symbol `\diagup`, which requires the `amssymb` package. There are a variety of techniques for creating new characters by superimposing one character on another. See for example [this question and its answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/480768/125871).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\disjoint}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\disj@int\relax}}
\newcommand{\disj@int}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    \hfil$\m@th#1\cap$\hfil\cr
    \hfil$\m@th#1\diagup$\hfil\cr
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\disjoint B$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple combination of `\mathpalette` and `\ooalign`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\disj}{\mathrel{\vphantom{\cap}\mathpalette\disj@\relax}}
\newcommand{\disj@}[2]{%
  \ooalign{$\m@th#1\cap$\cr$\m@th#1\neg$\cr}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
A\disj B
\\
\bigcup_{A\disj B}C_A
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The “lucky” circumstance is that `\neg` and `\cap` have exactly the same width in the Computer Modern math fonts (one might not be so lucky with other fonts).